# Is there any way to setup grid nodes from the hub node remotely?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid2

I have one hub and 4 nodes having different OS and browsers. Now I can set this up manually by going to the these 4 nodes and run the selenium node registration commands.

What I want is that I should be able to do the node configuration from the hub itself remotely and I don't have to go to nodes.

Is this possible with selenium grid?

Answer (score 0):

without other script or tool help is not possible.  The big stone block to register remote node from hub server is each remote node need to use a port from self when register to hub, it means the register command have to run from remote node.

Even you can specify the node ip and port and execute register command on hub server, but hub server can't communicate with the node, because the specified port never be run for register process (hub server can't to setup a connection chanel on the port on remote node).

You can try to write a script on hub server, when the script running, it will copy
the nodeConfig.json to remote node and execute the register command on remote node. I think this is feasible with some tools help.

If your hub server and node machines all are linux OS, it's easy to archive that, 
I'm not a linux shell expert, but i know it can be implemet.

Comment: I can do this by doing SSH to the remote node.

Comment: you can create node config json for each node and put them on hub server, then create a shell script on hub server to do following things: 1. use scp to copy node config json to remote node; 2. use ssh to login remote node to run register  command with node config json.